# Identify Missing DLLs in Python on Windows

Tags: python, windows, dll, importerror

If you try to import a `pyd` file in Python on Windows and you're missing some DLLs it depends on you'll get an error:

```
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found
```

Is there a way to show the name of the file you were trying to load and, more critically, the names of the missing DLLs?

I do not develop regularly on Windows, but I distribute a Windows version of a library I maintain and the lack of clarity around this error makes troubleshooting difficult, but I'm not sure how to get more information. I have found how to list the DLLs an extension requires, but I'd like to be able to do that in-place in my module to diagnose issues with user systems.

Comment: [Show loader snaps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/show-loader-snaps).

Comment: That looks relevant, but is there a way to access it in Python? Ideally rather than showing the generic error above I'd like to show an error like "you're missing XYZ.dll" (sorry for not being more clear)

Comment: Upgrading to Python 3.8 might be helpful, as it [includes the DLL shortname in the error](https://bugs.python.org/issue36266).

Comment: I suppose that is an error reported from a failed OS call to `LoadLibrary`. It fails if the module cannot be found **or one of its dependencies**. In the latter case the OS will not report which dependency could not be resolved.